# How do you send a programs current working directory in C using the winsock2 library?

Tags: python, c, sockets, encoding, winsock2

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main(){
    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);

    SOCKET serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(6969);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    listen(serverSocket, 1);

    int s_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &s_size);

    char cwd[1024];
    getcwd(cwd, 1024);

    printf(cwd);

    send(clientSocket, cwd, sizeof(cwd), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

It is meant to send the cwd of the program to a python script but whenever I run the python script it gives me this error when it recieves the cwd:

```
cwd = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 44: invalid continuation byte
```

Whenever I print the cwd on the C program it prints without any problem.
I have tried null terminating the string like this:

```
cwd[strlen(cwd)] = 0;
```

It didn't change anything.

My best guess is that the data between the actual path and the null terminator is what's causing the encoding error on the python scripts end, but I cant allocate just enough memory for the path because I can't know the length of the path before allocating memory, so I chose 1024 as I felt it was a sensible value.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

EDIT:
 I solved it. The cwd string had a lot of garbage in it along with the actual string because of the large buffer size (1024). I managed to allocate memory for cwd instead and reallocate it to its strlen().

```
char *cwd = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
getcwd(cwd, 1024);
realloc(cwd, strlen(cwd));

printf(cwd);

send(clientSocket, cwd, strlen(cwd), 0);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You're sending the full `char` buffer, including the junk after the NUL byte. Try `send(clientSocket, cwd, strlen(cwd) + 1, 0);`

Comment: Now it gives me this error:
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Comment: Is the Connection Reset coming from the python program (as I expect), or from the sending program in C?

Comment: You should [close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-closesocket) `clientSocket`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Python but believe I see what's going on here: it appears to be an impedance mismatch between two different ways of handling strings. This will take a few steps.

On the C side, it's a buffer of characters:

```c
char cwd[1024];
getcwd(cwd, sizeof cwd);
send(clientSocket, cwd, sizeof(cwd), 0);
```

and the contents of the `cwd` buffer *after* the current directory string are going to be a NUL byte plus random trash from the stack, and this whole buffer is being sent across the network to the Python program.

My initial proposal was to send only as much of the data as was valid:

```c
send(clientSocket, cwd, strlen(cwd), 0);  // don't do this after all
```

which sends no trash, but now we find the other problem: the receiving side is expecting a full 1024 bytes:

```c
cwd = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

The problem is, the sender is transmitting far less bytes (the length of `/home/steve/myproject` or whatever), and since a TCP socket doesn't honor message boundaries, it's still trying to read a full 1024.

I suspect that the Connection Reset is because your C program exits after sending, which closes the socket, and the Python side observes this closure before it was done receiving everything.

The proper way to fix this likely involves timeouts and buffering on the receiving side, but this looks like a lot of work, so I'll change direction a bit.

Now we'll go back to sending a fixed-size buffer (the 1024 as you suggest), which means both sides agree on the data size, but you'll have to modify the Python side to extract only the interesting part of the string, ignoring the NUL byte and what's beyond it.

On the Python side, you'll still do the `cwd = clientSocket.read(1024)` but then you'll have to do buffer manipulation to find out where the first NUL byte is, and only use up to (but not including) that character in the buffer.

The resulting subset (say, 47 bytes) will be a string that you should be able to decode and use.

Your results may vary depending on how Python allows you to manipulate buffers and turn them into strings; I don't know.

Comment: This sounds like a possible solution. So in the C code, when I add a null terminator on the end of the string, does it add it onto the end of the memory section or just the end of the valid characters? I thought it would add the 0 at the end of the garbage data, so I would have actual data, garbage data and the nul terminator on the end.

Comment: @dekotu - When you add a NUL byte, it goes into *one position* inside the character array, immediately after the character you care about (`/home/steve/myproject/`), but everything after the NUL byte is unknown and probably junk.

Comment: It is not trying to read a full 1024 characters. It will stop at whatever has been read.

Comment: I managed to solve it. I dynamically allocated cwd and then reallocated it to its strlen().